# Проверка наличия класса в документе при выборе из списка

Tags: jquery, классы

При клике на `select` или выборе любого элемента из него, нужно проверить имеется ли элемент с классом "test" на странице.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 5//EN" ttp://www.w3.org/TR/html5/html5.dtd">
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $('.form-select').change(function () {
            if ($('.test').length) {
            // console.log('true');
                alert ("test");   
            };
        });

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
       <select class="form-select">
    <option value="1">2</option>
    <option value="2">2.5</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <div class="">1</div>
    <div class="">2</div>
    <div class="test">3</div>
    <div class="">4</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Как такое можно сделать на Jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.form-select').change(function(){
   if ($('.test').length) { console.log('true'); }
});
```

Comment: пример поправил. в нем не работает. что то не так делаю?

Comment: У вас ошибка внешняя где то, потому что ваш скопированный вариант здесь прекрасно работает http://jsfiddle.net/LscUh/

Comment:      $('.form-select').change(function () {
            if ($('.test').length){
                alert ("test");   
            };
        });


если что то не работает то можете заменить $ на jQuery , может быть проблема в конфликте или же можно попробовать:

    jQuery.noConflict();
     (function( $ ) {
      $(function() {
       // More code using $ as alias to jQuery
      });
     })(jQuery);


Comment: мистика) буду разбираться. 
конфликтовать просто не с чем, т.к. даже в демке не работает. а там 1 скрипт и jquery.

Comment: В консоле напишите `$('.test').length` что покажет..

Comment: разместил скрипт в конце страницы и заработало. видимо он только после загрузки всего документа срабаотывает

Comment: разместил скрипт в конце документа. и все заработало.